# HTML5 rotate element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I am developing a web game that mimic deck shuffling and I want to use a canvas to represent a card. I want to know if there is a way to rotate an element with jquery or other library so that the element is no longer X-Y-aligned. I know I can rotate the canvas coordinate system, but I need to make the canvas larger than the card to render the rotating card. Is there a way to rotate an element directly? Thank you very much!

Comment: css transform rotate will rotate an element

Comment: in canvas you can use context.rotate [canvas rotate](http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/)

Answer (score 2):

After you draw your card to html canvas, your card is just a painting.

You can't reposition it because it's just pixels on the canvas.

What you do is:

- draw your card
- wait a short time
- clear the canvas
- redraw your card with a slightly new rotation
- repeat, repeat, repeat!

You can use html5's requestAnimationFrame (RAF) to do the waiting.  RAF will execute a function after about 16ms.  It's like a loop that you can put your code into and it often looks like this:

```
function animate(){

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);  // this will re-execute animate() in about 16ms

    // draw a current animation on the canvas

}
```

To effectively rotate the card:

- save the unrotated state of the canvas context (context.save)
- move to the center of your card's position (context.translate)
- rotate the canvas a bit (context.rotate)
- (it will rotate around your card's centerpoint since you "translated" to the centerpoint)
- draw the card (context.drawImage)
- restore the canvas context to its unrotated state.

That would look like this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(100,100);
ctx.rotate(rotation);
ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
ctx.restore();
```

Here is example code and a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/X9Wam/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var rotation=0;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    animate();
}
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/card.png";

        function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                // Drawing code goes here
                rotation+=Math.PI/120;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(100,100);
                ctx.rotate(rotation);
                ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
                ctx.restore();
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```